# How to transfer saved colors from computer to computer?

Tags: qgis, color

I have a ton of colors saved on the color palette and I was wondering how to transfer this color palette from a machine using QGIS 1.10 to a machine using QGIS 1.12.

Comment: QGIS 1.10 & 1.12 or **QGIS 2.10 & 2.12**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In color picker window go to Color Swatches tab and just export your palette to new .gpl file:

[image]